# TortoiseSVN Commit failed: Error: Commit failed (details follow): Can't open '\\directory\Subdirectory\db\svn-4FEBA748': Insufficient disk space

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn, samba

When commiting changes, SVN returns the next message:

Commit failed (details follow):  Can't open '\directory\Subdirectory\db\svn-4FEBA748': Insufficient disk space, even when both the client and server have enough disk space.

Client is windows 10 and server Zentyal box.

Commit is to a Samba shared directory.

Samba version 4.1.17-Zentyal

It was working O.K. and suddenly it is not.

Does somebody have an idea why is it happening?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, there is no question. Here it is: Does somebody have any ideas why is it happening? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mind editing the question to include that?

Comment: Sorry, new user!

Answer (score 1):

I finally discovered what happened. In fact, somebody activated disk quota in the unix box.  Even when quotacheck tells: "quotacheck: Your kernel probably supports journaled quota but you are not using it", if I go and edit user properties, using Zentyal User Management page, it has 50GB disk quota.

Thanks.